# Using Images uploaded on Strapi on Nuxt front end

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

Below is my API data exposed from strapi.

http://myjson.com/1fgx71

I have a column `post_content` which is a markdown, I have uploaded image there using WYSIWYG editor. Now images uploaded has path of

```
/uploads/f8d87d8b6b1e41fe9ecd965078c57dc1.png
```

This is the path on my Strapi server which has port of 1337.

Now on my Nuxt app I try to show this content using VueShowDown, obviously it gives error as file not found because Nuxt runs on port 3000, and there is no file present on Nuxt directory, file is stored on strapi server.

In such cases how do I show the image, which is stored on Strapi on my front end.

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't check if you already created an issue on the GitHub repo but if you can do it I will appreciate. I tested it and yes, there is an enhancement to do here.
And I agree with the answer below, it's recommended to use an external provider to store your files.

Answer (score 8):

hi you can create a computed variable and replace all '/uploads/' strings before show in template like:

```
data() {
    return {
        strapi_url: 'https://url-from-your-strapi.com' 
    }
}, computed: {
    changed_post_content: function () {
        return post_content.split('/uploads/').join(`${this.strapi_url}/uploads/` );
    }
},
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way right now is to add to every image in your vue app the url and the port that your strapi app is using. For example, if you're running strapi in you local development enviroment in the default port, then you will need to add localhost:1337 as prefix to test.

The reason is that you are using the default way to upload images in your app and strapi save the url without the domain.

I think you can create an issue on the strapi repository and specify if you want to try this as an issue or as an enhancement.

Last, I also think that is a good idea to use an external service like S3 form amazon or blob storage from azure to upload your static files. This problem is not present on those services. I'm using azure blob storage and strapi is saving the files with the correct url. See the image below

[Url created on a response using azure blob storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIEok.png)

Here is a provider list that you can use for your project, just remember that the only officially supported package is for AWS.

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=strapi-provider-upload-

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html#upload

Comment: Thank you Abraham, I am with you. Right now not thinking of going to any cloud. still at very early stage.  Right now what I did is I copied the uploads folder from Strapi and put it in my under Nuxt/Static folder. Not a elegant way I know.

Answer (score 1):

at first u need to GET `post_content` with something like `axios` or `opolo` from strapi and save it as a data in your frontend. write your function in `created(){},` the url in of the image would be something like  `post_content.image.url` then if u write

```
<img :src=`https://www.example.com${post_content.image.url} + ` />
```

you will get url not defined thats coz nuxt is severside rendering u have to add a `v-if:"post_content.image"` attribute in ur img tag so that nuxt waits for the image to load and then read its url
Good luck ;)

Answer (score -1):

to have an image show on the frontend from strapi you can simply do one of the four below:

`<img :src="api_url + example.image.url" alt="" />` or

`<img :src="api_url + example.image[0].url" alt="" />` or

`<img :src="`http://localhost:1337 `+ example.image.url" alt="" />` or

```
<img :src="`https://www.example.com` + example.image.url" alt="" />
```

replace example with your query name such as post_comment.image.url

I had this issue with both Gridsome and Nuxtjs and couldn't find help anywhere, now that i got it to work on various websites i built. I'm sharing the knowledge. Good Luck

Comment: OP is asking about images in Markdown/WYSIWYG not image assets