# Bad Link on strapi Image URL

Tags: vue.js, url, strapi

I am stuck with a question that i can't find a way to deal with. Please Help. I am building a front using VueJs and i make some API calls to my back-office managed on Strapi. Everything works fine with string content type but when i try to get an image response, i can't handle the good url to display my image.

Here is my HTML Code :

```
<div v-for="catalog in catalogs" :key="catalog.id">
            <p>{{ catalog.attributes.Title }}</p>
            <img :src="catalog.attributes.Cover.data.attributes.url" />
            <p>{{ catalog.attributes.createdAt }}</p>
        </div>
```

And here is my JSON :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "Title": "Catalogue Général 2023",
                "createdAt": "2023-03-16T10:18:57.910Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-03-16T10:48:13.184Z",
                "publishedAt": "2023-03-16T10:48:13.182Z",
                "Cover": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "attributes": {
                            "name": "Canson-Fine-Art---Graphic-arts-XLbristol.jpg",
                            "alternativeText": null,
                            "caption": null,
                            "width": 800,
                            "height": 800,
                            "formats": {
                                "thumbnail": {
                                    "name": "thumbnail_Canson-Fine-Art---Graphic-arts-XLbristol.jpg",
                                    "hash": "thumbnail_Canson_Fine_Art_Graphic_arts_X_Lbristol_ff19217886",
                                    "ext": ".jpg",
                                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                    "path": null,
                                    "width": 156,
                                    "height": 156,
                                    "size": 7.77,
                                    "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_Canson_Fine_Art_Graphic_arts_X_Lbristol_ff19217886.jpg"
                                },
                                "small": {
                                    "name": "small_Canson-Fine-Art---Graphic-arts-XLbristol.jpg",
                                    "hash": "small_Canson_Fine_Art_Graphic_arts_X_Lbristol_ff19217886",
                                    "ext": ".jpg",
                                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                    "path": null,
                                    "width": 500,
                                    "height": 500,
                                    "size": 49.98,
                                    "url": "/uploads/small_Canson_Fine_Art_Graphic_arts_X_Lbristol_ff19217886.jpg"
                                },
                                "medium": {
                                    "name": "medium_Canson-Fine-Art---Graphic-arts-XLbristol.jpg",
                                    "hash": "medium_Canson_Fine_Art_Graphic_arts_X_Lbristol_ff19217886",
                                    "ext": ".jpg",
                                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                    "path": null,
                                    "width": 750,
                                    "height": 750,
                                    "size": 91.45,
                                    "url": "/uploads/medium_Canson_Fine_Art_Graphic_arts_X_Lbristol_ff19217886.jpg"
                                }
                            },
                            "hash": "Canson_Fine_Art_Graphic_arts_X_Lbristol_ff19217886",
                            "ext": ".jpg",
                            "mime": "image/jpeg",
                            "size": 87.49,
                            "url": "/uploads/Canson_Fine_Art_Graphic_arts_X_Lbristol_ff19217886.jpg",
                            "previewUrl": null,
                            "provider": "local",
                            "provider_metadata": null,
                            "createdAt": "2023-03-16T10:45:27.903Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2023-03-16T10:45:27.903Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

In my Json Answer i am getting the good file name. But here is the url sent within my console. :

http://localhost:5173/uploads/Canson_Fine_Art_Graphic_arts_X_Lbristol_ff19217886.jpg

This url is pointing to a file within my front folder, but the file is actually stored on my Strapi Back-office. I am looking for a way to change this url in image source to make it point to my Strapi Back. Any clue ?

Thanks,

I already tried this :

```
 <img :src="http://localhost:1137/catalog.attributes.Cover.data.attributes.url" />
```

This version sends me 500 internal error, saying that the syntax is wrong.

and this one :

```
<img src="http://localhost:1137/catalog.attributes.Cover.data.attributes.url" />
```

Reads the URL as a complete String

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Answer found with the help of : [Using Images uploaded on Strapi on Nuxt front end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447757/using-images-uploaded-on-strapi-on-nuxt-front-end)

I was having a syntax error that was preventing my code to work so i have changed the code and broke the link here was the good answer :

```
<img :src="`http://localhost:1337` + catalog.attributes.Cover.data.attributes.url" alt="" />
```